# Overwrite all .txt files in folder recursively

Tags: powershell

What is the code that I can use in PowerShell to overwrite the content of all .txt files in a folder and sub directories? So far,  I tried using the following.

Get all text files, including the ones in sub directories, and store them in `t` variable:

```
$t = get-childitem *txt -recurse
```

Then using `set-content` cmdlet to write into all the files

```
set-content $t -value 'hello'
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Please help.

P.S: I am a newbie.

Comment: You can directly pipe: `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Set-Content` to set the own filename as content or apply a value `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Set-Content -Value 'Hello'`

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help Set-Content -Parameter Path` - you will note that the parameter you are using by position requires a STRING and you are providing a fileinfo object. [*grin*] try piping the collection to `Set-Content` OR using a `ForEach-Object` call to pass the `$_ in by parameter name.

Comment: Well, the code in the above question does work, although quite inefficient, since, as you rightly said,  the parameters are 'string' supplied. The ForEach-object will be better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `$t` variable. You can use a pipe:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Set-Content -Value 'Hello!'
```

This will populate all files in the directory you're in plus all sub directories with `Hello!`

If you need to do processing for some reason and need the files in the variable, you can either use a pipe chain or just pipe the variable:

```bsh
$t = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse
# Do stuff with $t
$t | Set-Content -Value 'Hello!'
```

Microsoft Documentation:

[Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6)

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)